# Convert Javascript serialize to Javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, object

I have a textarea with an id of 'dataArrayField' which has code in it, example:

```
item1: {
    type: 'foo',
    fieldName: 'bar'}
},
item2: {
    type: 'cat',
    fieldName: 'dog'
}
```

I then run `var content = $('#dataArrayField').serialize();` on this textarea, which has a nem of `codeformat`, so the returned data would be something like:

`codeFormat=item1%3a+ etc etc`

I then use the `$.deparam(content)` Javascript plugin to turn the serialized string to an 
object.

This works, however, the only key that actually is returned, is the codeFormat name, then the value is the text in the field above, so I get something like this:

[image]

What can I do so that I can access all the information in the passed object!

Comment: Is `#dataArrayField` your `textarea` or `form`?

Comment: @ShannonHochkins I don't think so, you can `serialize` a `form` but not a `textarea`, just take a look at your `html`

Comment: You can definitely serialize a textarea..... @OscarJara, its working, and that's what I'm doing?

Comment: @OscarJara, http://api.jquery.com/serialize/, you can definitely serialize textareas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either put a valid JSON string in the `textarea` such as

`{"item1":{"type":"foo","fieldName":"bar"},"item2":{"type":"cat","fieldName":"dog"}}`

or you can use regular expressions as in [**THIS WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3AXxL/) to clean it up before applying `JSON.parse()`. As @jibsales has already pointed out, do not use `eval()`:

```
$(function() {
    var val = $('#dataArrayField').val().replace(/[\s']/g,'').replace(/(\w+)/g,'"$1"');
    val = '{' + val.replace(/\}\},/g,'},') + '}';
    console.log( JSON.parse(val) );
});
```

Comment: I Changed this to the accepted answer as everyone is saying do not use eval.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a string which represents a javascript object and want to create an actual object from that, one option would be to use eval.

```
var str = "item1: {type: 'foo',fieldName: 'bar'},item2: {type: 'cat',fieldName: 'dog'}";
var obj = eval('({' + str + '})');
alert(obj.item1.type); // foo!
```

If a user can enter text that is later displayed to other users, this is probably not a very secure thing to do.

Comment: It would be safer to use `JSON.parse()`

Answer (score 1):

Eval is evil. Consider using JSON.serialize() and JSON.parse() instead. The objects entered in the text area will have to be valid JSON but it is much more secure.